# How to print contents of Java object without using getters

Tags: java

Actually i am implementing one program in which i am retrieving information from database and i am setting that info to One Object using setters and i just want to print that Object parameters without using `system.out.println(object.getHeadCount());`

I just want like if i am giving `system.out.println(object);` so using this code it should print data in Json format or any other readable format.

How to do it.Because my object is containing 30 fields so it is very hectic to write 30 getters to print data.

Comment: Override `toString()`

Comment: How Vince. Can u give me any example

Comment: You could google an example. Tons of examples online.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Comment: You have to override `toString()` to print object content without using getter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to override `toString()`

Normal way

```
class User {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public User(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
}
```

Using [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringBuilder.html)

```
class User {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public User(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return new ToStringBuilder(this)
            .append("firstName", firstName)
            .append("lastName", lastName)
            .toString();
    }
}
```

Using [Google Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/MoreObjects.html)

```
class User {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public User(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
            .add("firstName", firstName)
            .add("lastName", lastName)
            .toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to override the `toString()` method of the class, read about it in java doc for [Object class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()). Most IDE support it's automatic generation for all the fields of your class or for a number of them. Just for example:

```
class User {
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    User(String name, String surname)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.name+" "+this.surname;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override `toString()` method. if you are using eclipse then you can try right-click within the editor, you'll find it under `Source -> Generate toString()`

Answer (score 0):

To make a toString method you can simply just add one like so.

```
public String toString(){
    return "" + getValue();
}
```

The toString method is a part of

> java.lang.Object

So it is implemented in every class.